# Tag filter with OR condition

Tags: blueprism

I have four items with tags

"AA","BB","CC" and "DD" respectively.

If I want to filter tags in 
             Get Next Item stage 
such that items with 
             either tag "AA" or "BB" 
get picked then what should be tag filter expression?

I tried 
"+AA;+BB" 
But it did not pick any item.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of that object you can find following information about using parameter "tag" when getting new items from the queue.

> Optionally, a tag mask to filter by. This can consist of any number of
>   tag searches - each term can be separated by a semi-colon and they are
>   all applied to the search **(ie. they are AND'ed terms not OR'ed terms)**.
>   For example, "Account: Joint; -Balance: Overdrawn; Card: *Visa*" will
>   include any items which match all the terms, ie. every item must have
>   an 'Account: Joint' tag applied, no item can have a 'Balance:
>   Overdrawn' tag applied, every item must have a tag applied which
>   starts with 'Card: ' and then contains the text 'Visa'.

The important part in that documentation, is that all the parameters are applied, and only the items that pass all the filters with be taken from queue. I think that what you're trying to achieve here is impossible to do in one "Get next item" action.

i would advise to do one of following:

- Redesign the Tags in the process
- Use Two step process of getting items from queue there. E.g. First try to find all AA's, and then all BB's.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to filter by setting "-CC;-DD", so Blue Prism filter by searching for AA or BB but without CC and DD.